# Using Location services abroad without roaming charges

Tags: iphone, geolocation, gps, maps

I have an offline maps application (maps.me) on my iPhone 5S GSM.

Can I use the location services function abroad without getting charges for roaming when Cellular data is turned off?

(Only data is turned off. The normal telephone network is active and online.)

Please see the screenshots below for my current configuration:

[image: Cellular configuration]

[image: Location services configuration]

If you need any further information, please ask in the comments.

Comment: Don't you have a separate switch for Data Roaming? That's the one I leave off permanently. WiFi & GPS will work just fine for location services when abroad, if data roaming is off. It also uses the phone masts to get a rough idea first. [edit - I just checked, the Data Roaming switch disappears if you turn off all cell data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long you are using the Network provide they will charge you. Voice or Data or both.

Location service also works with GPS, Bluetooth (only short range) and WiFi.

As long you are in a free WiFi (and turn off voice and data) it is the best way to avoid any surprise charges.

Comment: If I then turn off Cellular data, will the location services still work via GPS without charges?

Comment: Yes it will work, GPS is not provided by Cellular. Your location accuracy might not be so good, but at least no charges will apply.